# How to Send an Email Verification for a Created User?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-mail, laravel-authentication

I'm trying to use Laravel 5.7's new **email verification feature**. Let's say I'm logged in as **Admin** inside the admin panel and I want to:

1. Create a random user via admin panel.
2. Send an email verification to that created user's email.

---

How can I accomplish this with the new Laravel 5.7 email verification feature?

Comment: Have you looked at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built in verification scaffolding provides a notification to do this. You just need to ensure that the user's `verified_at` is set to null and then

```
use Iluminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail;

$user->notify(new VerifyEmail);
```

This will resend a new email with a signed URL.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for.